# Can the multimapping of Petapoco handle multiple JOINs?

Tags: join, mapping, dapper, petapoco

I have a list objects I use to fill using Petapoco.

The class properties and names are maching the database schema. The main class is ***Issue***, and it is related to two other classes which names and properties matches the database schema too : ***Condition*** and ***SeverityLevel***.

```
public class Issue
{
    public int Id { get; set; } // Primary key

    /* Some properties... */
    public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    /* ... */

    // Related source and target conditions
    [PetaPoco.Ignore]
    public Condition SourceCondition { get; set; }

    [PetaPoco.Ignore]
    public Condition TargetCondition { get; set; }

    // Related severity level
    [PetaPoco.Ignore]
    public SeverityLevel CurrentSeverityLevel { get; set; }
}

public class Condition
{
    public int Id { get; set; } // Primary Key
    public string Description  { get; set; }
}

public class SeverityLevel
{
    public int Id { get; set; } // Primary key
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string HexColorDisplay { get; set; }
}
```

Actually, when I retrieve a list of Issues, I am using the multimapping feature to retrieve ***Issue*** list and related ***SeverityLevel*** using a single command :

```
var Results = Db.Fetch<Issue, SeverityLevel, Issue>(
    (i, sl) => { 
        i.CurrentSeverityLevel = sl;
        return i;
    },
    "SELECT /* ..shortened.. */ FROM Issue " + 
    "LEFT JOIN SeverityLevel ON SeverityLevel.Id = Issue.SeverityLevelId " + 
    "WHERE Issue.Id=@0", issueId);
```

Now, because Petapoco does not seems to handle multiple JOINS, I need to do a second step to attach ***SourceCondition*** and ***TargetCondition*** to each Issue I retrieved.

To do so, I could either :

- attach the Source and the Target condition after a Read, in a foreach loop,
- or retrieve the whole list of Condition, then attach then to each Issue using the same kind of for-each.

For now, I am using the second solution because there is a limited set of Condition in the database.

Anyway, it sounds a bit heavy to me to do this way, because it requires almost as many queries to be done as JOINED tables are added.

I wonder if I could achieve to make work something like this  :

```
var Results = Db.Fetch</* ????? */>(
    /* ???? */
    "SELECT /* ..shortened.. */ FROM Issue " + 
    "LEFT JOIN SeverityLevel ON SeverityLevel.Id = Issue.SeverityLevelId " + 
    "LEFT JOIN Condition Con1 ON Con1.Id = Issue.SourceConditionId " + 
    "LEFT JOIN Condition Con2 ON Con2.Id = Issue.TargetConditionId " + 
    "WHERE Issue.Id=@0", issueId);
```

Dear Petapoco users, dear Petapoco author, is this a way to handle this ?

Could I use Dapper to deals with this instead (if it can...), appart I absolutely want to keep Petapoco for my update/insert operations ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should be able to be done.

```
var Results = Db.Fetch<Issue, SeverityLevel, Condition, Condition, Issue>(
    (i, sl, c1, c2) => { 
        i.CurrentSeverityLevel = sl;
        i.SourceCondition = c1;
        i.TargetCondition = c2;
        return i;
    },
    "SELECT Issue.*, SeverityLevel.*, Con1.*, Con2.* FROM Issue " + 
    "LEFT JOIN SeverityLevel ON SeverityLevel.Id = Issue.SeverityLevelId " + 
    "LEFT JOIN Condition Con1 ON Con1.Id = Issue.SourceConditionId " + 
    "LEFT JOIN Condition Con2 ON Con2.Id = Issue.TargetConditionId " + 
    "WHERE Issue.Id=@0", issueId);
```

I have not tested this.
I am also working on a way to automate this.

It's **really** important that the columns selected are in the same order that the parameter types are.

Comment: It's working ! Thanks a lot. I think we reach the limits here, as I can not add more joins.

Comment: It is possible, you just have to use the non-generic overload, or if you are using dotnet 4.0 you can add your own overloads which take more parameters. 4 is the limit of .net 3.5.